# A website for all screen size resolution

Tags: html, css

I want to resize my website to different screen resolution.
I have set up my css like this but it doesn't work:

```
body {
    background: #317070;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
    margin : 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

what should I do ?
RQ: I have checked this link : http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Edit

Also I have

```
html {
    margin:0;
        padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: what 'doesn't work' about it?

Comment: @MLeFevre when I open my website on a smaller screen , the half of website appear (I have to scroll down)

Comment: if it's the height use html { height:100%; } and further on your question is very limited...

Comment: Do you have width and height 100% in html aswell?

Comment: Any block level HTML element will expand to fit the available width by default. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

You can block the scrolling with overflow: none; but in that case you will just hide some of the text completely. What is your aim - to change the text also according the resolution or what? Vertical scrolling is quite normal for smaller screens.

Comment: overflow: none; is not the answer, like it says it will hide the overflowing stuff... Julie you need to read the css-tricks again...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit limited so this is as far is i come

```
body,html {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  font-size:16px;
}
/* max-width of an image is 100% width, images will shrink at a smaller screen */
img { 
  max-width:100%; 
}
/* for example, smaller font-size at a lower resolution of smaller then 480px */
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  body { font-size: 0.8em; }
}
```

For mobile sreens you can take a look at viewports:[Viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)